# data from class using linq

Tags: c#, linq

Class

```
public partial class DT_createdRentalObject {

    private SimpleData masterDataField; -> Name

    private Address[] addressField; -> AddressName

    private Association[] associationField; -> AssociationName, AssociationId

}
```

How to write in LINQ

```
 public string createdRentalObject(DT_createdRentalObject ro)
{
 var list = (from s in ro ...?
}
```

**This structure:**

**|Name|    |AddressName|   |AssociationName| |AssociationId|**

Rafal   AFRICA  TS 1

Rafal   USA TA 2

Rafal   GERMANY TS 1

Rafal   FRANCE  TA 2

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking.  Can you clarify?  Maybe show an attempt to try to demonstrate?

Comment: I get all data from wcf to this structure of class. And I need prepare one list form this class. In this case I can try use "loop for" to take all elements but this is not good way.

Comment: Show please *"not a good way"* (code snippet), describe why it is not a good and tell us what you want. Then it become a question which can be answered.

Comment: Do you want all combinations of addresses and associations or should they be matched up by index (e.g. `address[0] + association[0]`, `address[1] + association[1]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try tis

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Test test = new Test();
            var list = test.rentalObjects.Select(x => new
            {
                Name = x.masterDataField.data,
                AddressName = x.addressField.FirstOrDefault().address,
                AssociationName = x.associationField.FirstOrDefault().AssociationName,
                AssociationId = x.associationField.FirstOrDefault().AssociationId
            }).ToList();
        }
    }
    public class Test
    {
        public List<DT_createdRentalObject> rentalObjects { get; set; }
        public Test()
        {
            rentalObjects = new List<DT_createdRentalObject>() {
                new DT_createdRentalObject() {
                    masterDataField = new SimpleData() { data = "Rafal"},
                    addressField = new Address[] { new Address() {  address = "AFRICA" }},
                    associationField = new Association[] { new Association() {  AssociationName = "TS",   AssociationId = "1" }}
                },
                new DT_createdRentalObject() {
                    masterDataField = new SimpleData() { data = "Rafal"},
                    addressField = new Address[] { new Address() {  address = "USA" }},
                    associationField = new Association[] { new Association() {  AssociationName = "TA",   AssociationId = "2" }}
                },
                new DT_createdRentalObject() {
                    masterDataField = new SimpleData() { data = "Rafal"},
                    addressField = new Address[] { new Address() {  address = "GERMANY" }},
                    associationField = new Association[] { new Association() {  AssociationName = "TS",   AssociationId = "1" }}
                },
                new DT_createdRentalObject() {
                    masterDataField = new SimpleData() { data = "Rafal"},
                    addressField = new Address[] { new Address() {  address = "FRANCE" }},
                    associationField = new Association[] { new Association() {  AssociationName = "TA",   AssociationId = "2" }}
                },
            };

        }

        public partial class DT_createdRentalObject
        {
            public SimpleData masterDataField { get; set; } //-> Name
            public Address[] addressField { get; set; } //-> AddressName
            public Association[] associationField { get; set; } //-> AssociationName, AssociationId
        }
        public class SimpleData
        {
            public string data { get; set; }
        }
        public class Address
        {
            public string address { get; set; }
        }
        public class Association
        {
            public string AssociationName { get; set; }
            public string AssociationId { get; set; }
        }

    }
}
​
```

Comment: It`s great answer I gave you point and accepted answer. Tahnks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a list of createdRentalObjects eg `List<createdRentalObject>`

```
public string createdRentalObject(**List<DT_createdRentalObject**> ro)
{
  List<createdRentalObject> aList = ro.Where(s=> s.masterDataField == "nameX").FirstOrDefault();
  // would give you a list where the masterDataField equals nameX
}
```

Download Linqpad https://www.linqpad.net/- and walk through the examples

Answer (score 1):

Since your sample data does not include all combinations of address and association, I'm assuming that they should be paired up by index.  `Zip` is one method to do that:

```
var list = 
    ro.addressField.Zip(ro.associationField, 
                        (add, asn) => new {ro.masterDataField.Name,
                                           add.AddressName,
                                           asn.AssociationName,
                                           asn.AssociationId}
                       );
```

Note that tihs must be done from *within* the `DT_createdRentalObject` class since the fields are private.